# Identation for custom HTML elements in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, webstorm, auto-indent

I am using **WebStorm 9.0.2** to create HTML templates which use containerless control flow syntax from **Knockout** ([Example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)) to conditionally display elements.

Here is an example:

```html
<div id="my-page">
  <!-- ko if: myObservable() -->
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  <p>It would be nice if things within ko:if are indented..</p>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Is there an option in WebStorm to define that everything inside a `<!-- ko if: ... ->` declaration must be indented?

Comment: [WEB-15684](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15684) - adding this comment for future references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Current situation is that the indentation can not be done automatically** for elements inside Knockout's containerless control flow syntax.

The wish to do that has been reported and you can [**vote for it**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15684) to be implemented in upcoming WebStorm releases.

### Current workaround

You can make the indentation manually and set the Auto Format so that it retains the manual indentation. To do that, you have to enable the **Formatter Control**. This can be done in <kbd>File → Settings → Editor → Code Style</kbd>:

[image: Enable Formatter Control]

When the Formatter Controls are activated, you are able to use the defined markers to prevent code within from being automatically formatted / aligned / indented. This works if you use the markers within comments of the specific language (works with multiple programming languages).

Here is an example for HTML and the original problem:

```
<div id="my-page">
  <!-- @formatter:off -->
  <!-- ko if: myObservable() -->
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <p>It would be nice if things within ko:if are indented..</p>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- @formatter:on -->
</div>
```

Many thanks to the WebStorm support team for [pointing this out](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/55374).

And if anyone would like to have a better solution, then please [vote for it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15684).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to specify at which points the indents will take place - however you can take a look at [Code Style - JetBrains Webstorm 9.0.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/code-style-javascript.html#d506939e130)